# Different run behaviour with same number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark

I have json data in .gz format (multiple files in KBs) as input on cloud storage. 1 day worth of input data has ~1.3 TB. Processing only 1 day data in spark. Spark code reads the data, applies a filter, derives nested columns from json object and write as delta to cloud storage. Using 15(w)+1(d) cluster with each having 16 cores and 64gb mem.

While reading the spark created ~62K tasks, took ~ 19min.
During write as delta format, partitionBy(day,city), spark created ~23K tasks, but job was aborted with message - Total size of serialized results of 6200 tasks (6.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize 6.0 GiB. tried increasing to 10GB, again failed.

when we executed the identical code with the same configurations, the only modification being the removal of "city" from the partitionBy , ie. ran with partitionBy(day), the job was completed successfully in approximately 1hr 15 minutes. This was achieved with an same number of tasks as described earlier during both the read (~62K) and write (~23K) phases.

```
maxPartitionBytes is set to 100MB by default
maxRecordsPerFile is set to 0 be default, infinite
```

what could be the reason for 1st job failing, where as both 1st and 2nd job have same number of tasks? Is there a way we resolve 1st job failure?

Comment: If you have data for X days and Y cities within one Spark partition, a `.write.patitionBy(day, city)` has a potential to write to upto X*Y delta partitions, compared to X patitions if you use 'day' only. Hence the serialized result of each task could be upto Y times larger.

Comment: Could you kindly provide a more details as an answer if possible, , as why the serialized result of each task could be upto Y times larger. Went through the other posts on web, could not understand much as we dont send any data to driver via collect()..etc in the code. Also what is serialized result in this context, given overall data volume s same. if there is a way to reduce number of tasks, if that helps in solving 1st job run issue.

Comment: If you open executor stderr log, you'll find messages like `"executor.Executor: Finished task 999.0 in Stage 99.0 (TID 99999). 9999 bytes result sent to driver"`. These 9999 or whatever bytes tallied over all the tasks, is the serialized result size the error message refers to.